# Better way to validate the form field combination with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample form with the following code (stripped for JSFiddle)

```
<input type="text" id="i1" />
<input type="text" id="i2" />
<input type="text" id="i3" />

<input type="text" id="e1"/>
<input type="text" id="e2" />
<input type="text" id="e3" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

The jQuery code follows (stripped for JSFiddle)

```
$("#e1").hide();
$("#e2").hide();
$("#e3").hide();
$("#submit").click(function(){
var a = $("#i1").val();
var b = $("#i2").val();
var c = $("#i3").val();

if (a == "" && b !== "" && c!=="") {
   $("#e1").show();
} else if (a !== "" && b == "" && c=="") {
   $("#e2").show();
   $("#e3").show();
} else if (a !== "" && b !== "" && c=="") {
   $("#e3").show();
}else if (a == "" && b == "" && c=="") {
$("#e1").show();
$("#e2").show();
$("#e3").show();
}
});
```

I am trying to validate the fields with possible combinations. It will show or hide the last three text fields (with id e*)accordingly if the fields are blank or not. For example, if the 1st field is empty and others are not, then e1 should be shown and others are hidden. Same of others like a typical form field were all fields are mandatory.  If I write the above code, it is too long and complex. Is there any simple solution for this kind of scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: It will show/hide the last three fields depending upon the value of first three input fields right?

Comment: @void yes. that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#e1").hide();
$("#e2").hide();
$("#e3").hide();

$("#submit").click(function(){

   $("input[id*=i]").each(function(i){
        if($(this).val()=="") $("#e"+(i+1)).show();
        else $("#e"+(i+1)).hide();
   });

});
});
```

Comment: Not working. What I want is if any of the field(s) is(are) empty, it will show the corresponding text fields (1->e1, 2->e2, 3->e3) and hide the non empty one.

Comment: Their was a typo mistake, Corrected now, Please check the updated code.

Comment: Think of e1 text boxes as alerts. If first text box is empty and others are not and submit button is clicked, it should alert fist text box empty. Like that, here, it should show or hide text boxes instead of alerts.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$("#e1").hide();
$("#e2").hide();
$("#e3").hide();
$("#submit").click(function(){
var a = $("#i1").val();
var b = $("#i2").val();
var c = $("#i3").val();

if (a == "") {
   $("#e1").show();
}if (b == "") {
   $("#e2").show();
   
}if (c == "") {
  
   $("#e3").show();
}

});
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i1" />
<input type="text" id="i2" />
<input type="text" id="i3" />

<input type="text" id="e1"/>
<input type="text" id="e2" />
<input type="text" id="e3" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eaaLxw04/)